# Where to learn about scrapy SgmlLinkExtractor?

Tags: python, scrapy

Sorry I am really new to python and scrapy, trying to learn them with trial and error.

Regarding SgmlLinkExtractor, I see everybody(at least on this site) is really proficient in finding the right code to represent the right path, where/how can I learn that? 
like `(allow=[r'page/\d+'])` or `allow=[r'series-\d{1}-episode-\d{2}.']` and etc etc.

I am trying to scrape off a website where its content is always in story.html, link format is like this:

http://www.example.com/folder/category/description/1234567/story.html

*note 1234567 is a changing 7 digits number

my start url is http://www.example.com/folder/

I am trying to use `SgmlLinkExtractor` and define my path as follows. I want to include whatever is in the description portion of url and the 7 digits portion. I want to make sure the url ends with `story.html`:

`Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'category1/././story\.html',)), callback='parse_item', follow=True)`,

But obviously the `/././` would not allow me to skip two sublevels to get to story.html

What is the right way to write this `SgmlLinkExtractor`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=(r'category1/description/\d+/story\.html',)), callback='parse_item', follow=True)
```

but i will recommend you to use only `/description/\d+/story\.html` this Part because its unique enough to crawl categories

in Rules we pass Regex , so you just simply needs to learn [regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) , there are bunch of [online regex tester](http://regexpal.com/) tools are available

Comment: Thank you very much. This is very helpful. regex is what I need to learn.